# Setting an instance variable to 'self'?

Tags: ruby, class, self

I'm creating Conway's Game of Life with two classes:  Board & Cell.

Board has access to Cell, but I'm not quite sure exactly how. Can't I place `cell.board = self` under Cell's initialize method? Why or why not? For sake of example, here's what I think are the relevant parts.

```
class Board
  #omitted variables & methods    

    def create_cell
        cell = Cell.new
        cell.board = self
    end
end

class Cell
    attr_accessor :board

    def initialize
    end
end
```

Also, what does `cell.board = self` do exactly?

Comment: You probably mean `Cell.new`, not `Class.new`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in your code. Instead of `cell = Class.new` you should do `cell = Cell.new`.
Yes you can pass the board (self) as a parameter in the Cell's constructor (initialize). In fact is more clean and functional in that way. Check out this code:

```
class Board
  def create_cell
    cell = Cell.new(self)
  end
end

class Cell
  attr_accessor :board

  def initialize board
    @board = board
  end
end
```

And then some examples of use.

```
$> b = Board.new
 # => #<Board:0x000001021c0298> 
$> c1 = b.create_cell
 # => #<Cell:0x000001021c27a0 @board=#<Board:0x000001021c0298>> 
$> c2 = b.create_cell
 # => #<Cell:0x000001021d4270 @board=#<Board:0x000001021c0298>> 
$> c2.board == c1.board
 # => true
```

As you can notice, either `cell.board = self` or using the `constructor` (initialize), is setting the current board instance into the created cell. So all these cells will point to that board.

Answer (score 1):

`cell.board = self` sets the cell's `board` variable to the current board object (that is the board object on which you called the `create_cell` method.

If you put `cell.board = self` into `Cell`'s `initialize` method, you'd get an error that `cell` is not defined in that scope. If you replaced it with `@board = self`, you'd set the `board` variable to the current `Cell` object (i.e. the one that's being created), not to a `Board` object. So that wouldn't be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You can assign `self` to anything. You can't assign something else *to* `self`, but there's nothing wrong with assigning `self` to any other accessable variable or passing it to a method.

You could, for example, have written

```
class Board
  #omitted variables & methods    

    def create_cell
        cell = Class.new(self)
    end
end

class Cell
    attr_accessor :board

    def initialize(board)
      self.board = board
    end

end
```

> Also, what does cell.board = self do exactly?

It just passes a variable to the `board=` accessor. It's no different from passing any other variable.

Comment: I've tried creating a new object `b = Board.new' and calling the `c1.create_cell` method, but it runs into an error: `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)`